# Command to run GCC compilation?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am using the GCC compiler but I want the to code the actually run after compilation. Is there a flag I can use for this? Right now I am just doing

```
  gcc code.c
```

There is no code.exe being generated...

Comment: On Unix: `gcc code.c -o code.exe && ./code.exe`.

Comment: How do you know he's referring to Unix? There is gcc available for Windows... in fact the OP never stated what environment. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b common, that's just a comment. If it was useful, take it. If not, just ignore it

Comment: @t0mm13b - in a windows shell, the command is: `gcc code.c -o code.exe && .\code.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file created by default is called a.out.  If you want to name it code.exe, the correct line should be `gcc -o code.exe code.c`

Answer (score 1):

The executable generated by GCC is called 'a.out' by default, unless you use the `-o` option to specify a name for your output file.

Comment: Under Windows, the default gcc-executable (at least here) is called `a.exe`.

Comment: Ah, right.  When I think 'gcc' I assume a *nix environment :)